# Can i use WCF Services to develop a Distributed System(as middleware)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am new to visual studio, and i developing a distributed system with visual studio, i'm developing two applications

1. windows forum application c#
2. Web application asp.net

so i using WCF Services to make this system distributed, is is right?

in web application im using a WCF Services to Login and insert data and retrive data.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, i can say WCF would be fine. But in future if you are planning to support your application on devices like smartphones/tablets then Web API would be better choice.
But its totally depend on the situation. You will get more info on the following link: 
http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/difference-between-wcf-and-web-api-and-wcf-rest-and-web-service

Hope this will help you to choose appropriate option for your application.